# Why this copy data from a point wrong？

Tags: delphi, pointers

this is my sample code :

```
type
  PData = ^TData;
  TData = record
    str : string;
    strlist : TStringList;
  end;

var
  P1 : PData;
  P2 : PData;
  P3 : PData;
  P4 : PData;
begin
  New(P1);
  New(P2);
  P1.str := 'string';
  // copy
  P2^ := P1^;
  P2.str := P2.str + '_copy';
  Memo1.Lines.Add('This is P1:' + P1.str); //This is P1:string
  Memo1.Lines.Add('This is P2:' + P2.str); //This is P2:string_copy

  // so change P2'Data didn't change P1's Data
  // but this :
  New(P3);
  New(P4);
  P3.str := 'string';
  P3.strlist := TStringList.Create;
  P3.strlist.Add('one line');
  // copy
  P4^ := P3^;
  // just add P4's data
  P4.strlist.Add('two line');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('P3''s Data:' + IntToStr(P3.strlist.Count));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(P3.strlist.Text);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('P4''s Data:' + IntToStr(P4.strlist.Count));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(P4.strlist.Text);
  {
   P3's Data:2
   one line
   two line

   P4's Data:2
   one line
   two line
  }
end;
```

why when copy point data with a `class` , it will change raw data , but when data is `string` use `P1^ := P2^` copy point data does not change raw data.

Comment: The best way to think about this is to consider that `string` is a value type. It has value type semantics, even if the implementation is funky. If you have a mental model that puts `string` in the same category as `Integer` and `Double` then you won't go wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String is somewhat of a Delphi-managed special entity. In particular, Delphi uses a `Copy-On-Write` strategy, i.e. when you do `P2^ := P1^;`, `P1.str` and `P2.str` both point to the same string object. Delphi keeps track via an internal reference count how many references to the string object exist.

As soon as you do a write operation like `P2.str := P2.str + '_copy'`, Delphi recognises that the string is in use more than once and creates an own copy for P2.str. This all happens in the background and normally you don't notice this.

On the other hand, P3.strlist and P4.strlist are ordinary pointers and always point to the same object. There is no automagical copying here whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are copied on demand. That means when you change the copied string, it will create a new instance of the changed string. For simplicity you can assume that a string copy is a copy of the string data.

When you assign a class instance only a pointer to that instance is copied, not the instance itself. After the copy there is still only one class instance. You can see that from your code as there is only one TStringList.Create in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that delphi makes a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) of objects.
A shallow copy means that all native data types are copied but that objects are only copied by reference.

So after the copy assignment both objects hold a reference to the same `strlist` object.

Answer (score 1):

You copy all the values from `P3` to `P4`.

**But** `strlst` ist just a reference to an Object `TStringList` and this **reference** is also copied and so `P4.strlst` points to the same object as `P3.strlst`